# Pre/Post-Handler Hook for Micronaut

Tags: rest, micronaut

I was wondering if there is some way to provide two methods to Micronaut which are guaranteed to run before and after a request was passed to the handler.

In my case, this would be to initialize some thread-local data.

I know this would also be possible to put in the handler itself but putting the same lines of code in every handler isn't really the greatest solution.

Comment: "I was wondering if there is some way to provide two methods to Micronaut which are guaranteed to run before and after a request was passed to the handler.  In my case, this would be to initialize some thread-local data." - What is an example of something you intend to use the thread local for after the request is passed to the handler?

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter - see the docs at https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#filters